# Phonegap Android App gedit on linuxmint

Tags: cordova

I want to develop android app using [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) but i am using linuxmint. I search on google but couldn't find any usefull link that can be usefull. please any one give me link or solution how i can develop app using phonegap on gedit without using java apis. because on [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) website they using "cordova-2.6.0.js" or eclipse its not usefull for me

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap apps are just web apps. You can't access the [API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/index.html) without the native code.

Ok, this is not completely true, there is [Ripple](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc) which allows you to test your PhoneGap app in Chrome, but it really is in a beta state.

Comment: i think didn't know about phonegap its better to learn first